# Error in: Can't resolve all parameters for 'Component' (?, [object Object])

Tags: angular

*I am running Angular 6.

I do not understand why I am getting this error.

I read through the similar SO questions on this error and there doesn't appear to be a definitive answer.

I have a base class:

```
 @Injectable()
    export class MyBase {       
      constructor(private uri: string, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

      public deleteCall(id: string) {
        return this.httpClient
         .delete(this.uri + "/" + id);
      };
   }
```

I have several classes that extend this class:

```
  @Injectable()
export class GizmoService extends ServiceBase {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super(environment.gizmoUri, http);
  }      
}
```

I would implement the service thoughout my application in this manner:

```
export class GizmoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private gizmoService: GizmoService,
    private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  deleteGizmo(id: string) {
    let deleteDialog = ...; 

    deleteDialog.afterClosed()
      .subscribe(x => {
        if (x === true) {
          this.gizmoService.deleteCall(id)
            .subscribe(() => this.loadDataSource());
        }
      });

  };
}
```

From what I can tell it seems to be an issue with passing the uri string from the derived class to the base class.

I've checked my app.module.ts and made sure that the derived classes are declared before the base class.

I don't see any circular reference in my example.

What is the cause of this error and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Do not mark the base class as `Injectable`. Otherwise it will try to inject "string" which has no injector

Comment: I removed the @Injectable from the the base class and still have the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the right class? You have two names `MyBase` and `ServiceBase`. Or is that a typo?

Comment: Also make sure you do not add the base class to providers in modules.

Comment: Once I removed it from the modules it the error went away.

Comment: @JDS You could post your own solution as an answer. It could be helpful to others.

Comment: Ok Silvermind I was waiting to give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

It related to `MyBase` class url parameter angular DI system try to inject this base on string as token but doesn't have it ,that why you got `(?, ...)` , so to solve this you need use `inject`

in `app.module` add `{provide:'url',useValue:'127.0.0.1'}` to providers list and update `MyBase` class like this

```
@Injectable()
    export class MyBase {       
      constructor(@Inject('url') private uri: string, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

      public deleteCall(id: string) {
        return this.httpClient
         .delete(this.uri + "/" + id);
      };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was 2 fold.  *Thanks to ExplosionPills and Silvermind

1. The base class was setup as @Injectable.  This was not needed because it will try to inject "string" which has no injector.
2. I had to remove MyBase from the providers in app.module.ts.

Once both of these steps were completed the error went away.